# C# aspx.cs for loop for adding numbers

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a for loop that just will not execute. It is supposed to take the firstNumber entered by the user and add each number between the secondNumber the user enters, together. For instance, firstNumber = 5 and second number = 8, the numberTotal should = 26 (5+6+7+8). I cannot seem to get my for loop to even start iterating. The label2 just assumes the initialized value and nothing else. Help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Menu_Items_and_Numbers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
        int numberTotal = 0;

        for(int i=firstNumber; i > secondNumber; i++)
        {

            numberTotal += i; 

        }

        Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(numberTotal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is supposed to take the firstNumber entered by the user and add
>   each number between the secondNumber the user enters, together. For
>   instance, firstNumber = 5 and second number = 8, the numberTotal
>   should = 26 (5+6+7+8).

Right here.

```
for(int i=firstNumber; i > secondNumber; i++)
```

So if a user enters 5 and 8, the execution is as follows:

```
for (int i=5 ; 5 > 8; i++)
```

and quits right there, because `5 > 8 ?= false` .

Remember that a for loop is :

```
for (initialize variable; while condition; increment variable)
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, I was thinking backwards on the while condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition on your for loop is incorrect.  The correct condition is:

```
for (int i = firstNumber; i <= secondNumber; i++)
{
    numberTotal += i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is invalid. Try this

```
    for(int i=firstNumber; i <= secondNumber; i++)
    {
        numberTotal += i; 
    }
```

or this:

```
numberTotal = Enumerable.Range(firstNumber, secondNumber - firstNumber + 1).Sum();
```

[Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) gives you all numbers from first till second number and Sum() sums them up.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this to make sure the firstnumber is always the smaller number

```
 for (int i = GetSmallerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber); i < GetLargerNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber); i++)
        {
            numberTotal +=i;
        }

public Int32 GetSmallerNumber(Int32 Number1, Int32 Number2)
    {
        if (Number1 < Number2)
            return Number1;
        else
            return Number2;
     }
 public Int32 GetLargerNumber(Int32 Number1, Int32 Number2)
    {
        if (Number1 < Number2)
            return Number2;
        else
            return Number1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first this way wont add the second number it because the for loop will stop at (second-1) because the next number will make it i = second , so if u want the second number to be add to you have to use second+1 instead of just second so it will be like

```
 for (int i = first; i < second+1; i++)
```

or

```
for (int i = first; i <= second; i++)
```

Second you will face a problem if the first number is bigger than the second number